# Navigation bar won't centre on smartphone devices

Tags: html, ios, css

The website I'm having issues with is [Bristol Plumber 247](http://www.bristolplumber247.co.uk) if you visit this site on your desktop or laptop, the nav bar is perfect however when I use my iphone it drops to under.

*I cannot post picture because I don't have 10 reputation on this site I am happy to email or just visit on mobile device and you will see what I mean.

I've look at the CSS and set nearly every width to 100% and Margin to 0 auto; I've look and looked and the code and was wondering if somebody would have a look at the code for me and tell me where am I going wrong. I'm at pulling my hair out stage.

Comment: It's not collapsing at all for me on mobile...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the wrapper according to CSS media screen like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .wrapper { width:1100px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .wrapper { width:980px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper { width:100%; }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay I've try this but still no luck?